# Allow multiple versions of the same package to be used by an app in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

One of the packages I use already uses a package (eg connectivity 0.4.9+2) due to some issues in this version I have to use connectivity 3.0.2. is there any way to use multiple versions of the same package in flutter?